# CGRectMake is not working in swift?

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I'm new to Swift . Not getting the subview when i clicked the FDatebutton

```
@IBAction func FDateButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    tag = 20
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    DatePicker.hidden = false
    DatePickerView.hidden = false
    DatePickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/4, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/2)
    DatePickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.65, green: 0.36, blue: 0.64, alpha: 1.0)
    self.view.addSubview(DatePickerView)

}
```

Comment: Where you declared the DatePickerView?

Comment: outside of my view controller

Comment: Can you edit the question with declaration and initialization code? You created custom view or it's an IBOutlet of the view?

Comment: In Swift, use `CGRect(x:, y:, width:, height:)` instead of `CGRectMake`.

Comment: everything is working correct , can u please tel me  how can i make one subview which should be come at centre of my main view

Comment: DatePickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/4, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/2)  self.view.window?.addSubview(DatePickerView) with this code ,i was forgot add window . thank you everyone

Comment: its working now with that code

Answer (score 0):

**Possibilities**

- If You have `Autolayout` enabled (which is actually enabled by default), setting frame to any `UIView` will not work until you will set `translateAutoresizingMaskToConstraints` to `false`
- Either disable the `Autolayout` and then set the frame property. (This is not a best way to do because using `Autolayout` is a best practise now a days.)

**Best Practise**

- Create a outlet of `NSLayoutConstraint` and connect it to your Interface Builder constraints you want to change at run time.
- Follow this tutorial for to know how to use [AutoLayout](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

**What you need to do**

- set `translateAutoresizingMaskToConstraints` to `false` for the `DatePickerView`

Hope that will work

Comment: "If You have Autolayout enabled (which is actually enabled by default), setting frame to any UIView will not work." ... That's not true. By default, if you don't turn off `translateAutoresizingMaskToConstraints` for a programmatically created view, when you set the `frame`, it will create the constraints for you.

Comment: Thanks @Rob for letting me know about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can print `datePickerView.frame` and use the Visual View Debugger in Xcode to see if and where is your view drawing.

I don't think that deriving your view size off the main window is a good idea. What if the user use split mode on an iPad? Will it still work the way you wanted? Using auto layout would be a better option.

Also, you are adding *new* sub view every time you click the `FDateButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Use CGRect(x:0 , y:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/4 , width:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width , height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/2) method instead of CGRectMake. correct your code , it will work properly.